# Carving or sculpting model ship decorations

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Good evening,
I am fairly new to Blender with the intent to 3D-print my own decorations for a ship model. I have looked at both wood carving and sculpting tutorials, but find it difficult to decide which way I should go (with further training). I have a picture attached to clarify. It appears to me as a carving, but the figures look more sculpted than what I could achieve with a carving approach (?). I would *very much* appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction how to approach this.
Piet

[image]

Comment: Hello, by carving do you mean using boolean objects to cut through a base mesh ?

Comment: @Gorgious. Thanks for responding and sorry for not being clear; probably a sign of my confusion. I am referring to placing curves along the outline of the decoration elements and then creating faces that are being manipulated. It appears this gives a less 'curvy' body than what can be achieved with sculpting.